# Javascript object is null after return

Tags: javascript, function, null, return

So I've been struggling with this and so I came here for answers. I feel like a bit of a JavaScript newbie with this question but here it goes.

I have the following this code:

```
function a() {
    var ret = {};
    //random stuff that get some other object
    ret = someOtherObject;
    alert(ret);
    return ret;
}

var c = a();
alert(c);
```

The problem is that "c" is null but "ret" is the correct object. Is the object not cloned on return? Does "ret" get lost and disappears outside the function? I don't get it.

Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Are you *sure* that's everything which is going on. The alert before the return has a value but the alert after calling the method does not? I betcha there's more to this than you've posted here.

Comment: What is `someOtherObject`? Change your testcase so that it works with an integer or something, and when that works, slowly start adding stuff until it breaks. Then you've found the culprit and can post a more specific question.

Comment: @Kooilnv: So it _doesn't_ replicate the issue, in fact.

Comment: In particular is a() is not defined twice in your code

Comment: That was it @Xavier Combelle! My text editor had screwed up my code and created a new a() function below. It works, now! :)

Comment: @Xavier, could you pass me your Crystal Ball? ;-)

Comment: @Capsule I supposed that if the a() showed did not returned the right answer there should be another a() which is called instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that if the a() showed do not return the right answer there should be another a() which is called instead.

So the problem is that there is two a() in the code one with the right definition the second you don't show us.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem. For me the issue was that I had

```
var i;
if (condition) {
    i = 1
}
return i
```

`i` was always null for me, even if the condition was true. Changing to `var i = null;` at the top fixed my problem

Answer (score -2):

JavaScript is asynchronous, so if running function a() take some time, variable c is still null if alert is called before a() return something. This can be fixed with callbacks, ie. wrap alert-code in function and call it from a().

Comment: -1 Unless you use asynchronous (Ajax) functions, Javascript IS synchronous.

Comment: I doesn't agree in normal javascript the code is not asynchronous

Answer (score -2):

Keep in mind that in JavaScript, variables do not need the `var` keyword to be defined.

That means with the line

```
ret = someOtherObject;
```

1. You first define a variable `someOtherObject` that is set to `null` by default.
2. You then assign `someOtherObject` to `ret` (right-to-left evaluation)

Therefore, `ret` becomes `null`.

Comment: While you don't need `var` to define them, variables aren't defined by referencing them, but only by assigning to them! `someOtherObject` will be unresolved.